# How to parse Int or Double in scala depending on value?

Tags: scala

I have a parser class which uses Apache POI to parse Excel files.

When a cell contains `1.0`, I would like to convert it to String `"1"`.
And when I get `1.1`I would like to parse it to `"1.1"`

How to do that ?

I have try some experiments without success like that:

```
try
  doubleValue.toInt
catch
{
  case _ => doubleValue.toString
}
```

Or by using the `Integer.parseInt()`method.

Comment: what's wrong with above code or what exception do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code returns an `Int` if possible, otherwise a `Double`

```
if (doubleValue.isValidInt)
  doubleValue.toInt
else
  doubleValue
```

You must beware that the common type between the two is `AnyVal`, and sometimes you should declare it explicitly to avoid the compiler to reconvert automatically the `Int` result to a `Double`.

P.S. if the outcome must be a `String`, you can pack the above code in a method and call `toString` on the result.